# Efficient querying of multi-partition Postgres table

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, partitioning

I've just restructured my database to use [partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/ddl-partitioning.html) in Postgres 8.2. Now I have a problem with query performance:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE time_stamp >= '2010-02-10' and time_stamp < '2010-02-11'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

There are 45 million rows in the table.  Prior to partitioning, this would use a reverse index scan and stop as soon as it hit the limit.

After partitioning (on time_stamp ranges), Postgres does a full index scan of the master table and the relevant partition and merges the results, sorts them, then applies the limit.  This takes way too long.

I can fix it with:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM my_table_part_a
  WHERE time_stamp >= '2010-02-10' and time_stamp < '2010-02-11'
  ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT 100) t
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM my_table_part_b
  WHERE time_stamp >= '2010-02-10' and time_stamp < '2010-02-11'
  ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT 100) t
UNION ALL
  ... and so on ...
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 100
```

This runs quickly.  The partitions where the times-stamps are out-of-range aren't even included in the query plan.

My question is: Is there some hint or syntax I can use in Postgres 8.2 to prevent the query-planner from scanning the full table but still using simple syntax that only refers to the master table?

Basically, can I avoid the pain of dynamically building the big UNION query over each partition that happens to be currently defined?

**EDIT:** I have constraint_exclusion enabled (thanks @Vinko Vrsalovic)

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried Constraint Exclusion (section 5.9.4 in the document you've linked to)

> Constraint exclusion is a query
>   optimization technique that improves
>   performance for partitioned tables
>   defined in the fashion described
>   above. As an example:

```
 SET constraint_exclusion = on; 
 SELECT count(*) FROM measurement WHERE logdate >= DATE '2006-01-01';
```

> Without
>   constraint exclusion, the above query
>   would scan each of the partitions of
>   the measurement table. With constraint
>   exclusion enabled, the planner will
>   examine the constraints of each
>   partition and try to prove that the
>   partition need not be scanned because
>   it could not contain any rows meeting
>   the query's WHERE clause. When the
>   planner can prove this, it excludes
>   the partition from the query plan.
>
> You can use the EXPLAIN command to
>   show the difference between a plan
>   with constraint_exclusion on and a
>   plan with it off.

Comment: Yes, I have constraint-exclusion switched on.  Unfortunately, the master table (which is always empty) is always included in the query as it's not possible to apply a CHECK constraint to it (at least in 8.2).  This means there's always at least two tables involved in the query

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem that I was able fix by casting conditions in WHERE.
EG:  (assuming the time_stamp column is timestamptz type)

```
WHERE time_stamp >= '2010-02-10'::timestamptz and time_stamp < '2010-02-11'::timestamptz
```

Also, make sure the CHECK condition on the table is defined the same way...
EG:
  CHECK (time_stamp < '2010-02-10'::timestamptz)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and it boiled down to two reasons in my case:

1. I had indexed column of type `timestamp WITH time zone` and partition constraint by this column with type `timestamp WITHOUT time zone`.
2. After fixing constraints `ANALYZE` of all child tables was needed.

**Edit**: another bit of knowledge - it's important to remember that constraint exclusion (which allows PG to skip scanning some tables based on your partitioning criteria) doesn't work with, quote: `non-immutable function such as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

I had requests with `CURRENT_DATE` and it was part of my problem.